# How to upload a file using af:inputFile in Oracle ADF

Tags: java, file-upload, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Can anyone please tell me how to upload file to server using af:inputFile in Oracel ADF. I searched about this and found we can use the following

```
<af:form usesUpload="true">
  <af:inputFile columns="10" 
                valueChangeListener="#{backing.fileUploaded}"/>
</af:form>
```

using the above code I can set a method that executes when some choose some file in the form. So now I need to know in fileUploaded method what should be the java code to upload the given file to the server.

Please help me. How I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already created value change listener in managed bean then use this code -

```
/**Method to Upload File ,called on ValueChangeEvent of inputFile
 * @param vce
 */

public void uploadFileVCE(ValueChangeEvent vce) {
    if (vce.getNewValue() != null) {
        //Get File Object from VC Event
        UploadedFile fileVal = (UploadedFile) vce.getNewValue();
    }
}
```

and this is the method to upload file on server (You have to provide absolute path)

```
/**Method to upload file to actual path on Server*/
private String uploadFile(UploadedFile file) {

    UploadedFile myfile = file;
    String path = null;
    if (myfile == null) {

    } else {
        // All uploaded files will be stored in below path
        path = "D://FileStore//" + myfile.getFilename();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
            inputStream = myfile.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle exception
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

    }
    //Returns the path where file is stored
    return path;
}
```

Check this thread on OTN Forum
https://community.oracle.com/message/13135474#13135474

Here you can read full implementation and download sample application to test
http://www.awasthiashish.com/2014/08/uploading-and-downloading-files-from.html

Full disclosure on the last link above and its contents: I wrote it and it is my TLD.

Answer (score 1):

Your inputFile should look something like the following where gciuiCheckin is a reference to the backing bean. In this case the inputFile control is in a jsff contained as a region inside a jspx with usesUpload="true", but this would be similar if you are putting your controls directly in the jspx, the main thing is you need to bind the control value to a backing bean variable of type UploadedFile:

```
<af:inputFile label=" " id="ifDoc" columns="50" 
  value="#{pageFlowScope.gciuiCheckin.filesToUpload}" 
  maximumFiles="#{pageFlowScope.gciuiCheckin.maxFilesCanBeUploaded}"
  autoHeightRows="0" rows="5" uploadType="auto"/>
```

Then you also should have a commandButton to call a bean method once user has selected the file (each file typically is uploaded to server as the user selects or drag drops each one):

```
<af:commandButton text="Commit File(s)" id="cbUpload" 
  partialSubmit="true" action="#{pageFlowScope.gciuiCheckin.saveUploadedFilesAction}"/>
```

You will need this import in the backing bean:

```
import org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.model.UploadedFile;
```

In the backing bean, create a List with accessors to hold the uploaded files:

```
private List<UploadedFile> filesToUpload;
```

In the method called by the commandButton, you will do something like:

```
public String saveUploadedFilesAction() {        
        List<UploadedFile> files = this.getFilesToUpload();

        if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {            
            displayMessageToUser(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, checkinErrorMessage);
            return null;
        }

        //iterate each file and check size, extension, etc...        
        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {                
            UploadedFile currFile = files.get(i);
            //now do something with the file...                
        }
        ...
```

Hope this helps.